# How to access nsIEditor of contentEditable elements?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, firefox-addon, xul

When my extension gets access to an `INPUT` (type `"text"`) or `TEXTAREA` element of the currently displayed webpage in Firefox, I can use `QueryInterface` to cast it to a JS object of type `nsIDOMNSEditableElement` and then I can access the associated `nsIEditor` using `.editor`.

However, Firefox supports other elements to be editable as well, e.g. any element (and its children) is editable if it has the attribute `contentEditable` set to `true`. Further a whole document can be editable if it has `designMode` set to `on`. In either case, the editable elements are not instances of `nsIDOMNSEditableElement`; `QueryInterface` for `nsIDOMNSEditableElement` fails.

Since those editable elements can also have spell checking enabled (if they have the attribute `spellcheck` set to `true`), I assume that there is an instance `nsIEditor` associated with them.

How would I get a reference to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For editable frames (via `designMode` property) you can retrieve it like this:

```
var session = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                    .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
                    .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                    .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIEditingSession);
if (session.windowIsEditable(window)
  editor = session.getEditorForWindow(window);
```

As to `contentEditable` - you seem to be out of luck. I couldn't find a way to access the editor from JavaScript: `nsGenericHTMLElement` class has a `GetEditor` method but it is only accessible through `nsIDOMNSEditableElement` interface that only few elements implement. [`nsIAccessibleEditableText` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NsIAccessibleEditableText#Attributes) has an `associatedEditor` property but it is marked as `[noscript]` for some reason. `contentEditable` is a relatively new feature in Gecko and it looks like somebody forgot to make the editor accessible for JavaScript - probably worth filing a bug at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/.